# Has PHP's behaviour changed?

Tags: php, character-encoding, php-5.3

Studying for the ZEND-CE exam, I came across this question:

> Given a php.ini setting of:
>      default_charset = utf-8
>   What will the following code print in the browser?
>
> ```
> <?php  
>
> header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');  
>
> echo '&#9986;&#10004;&#10013;';  
>
> ?>
> ```
>
> A. Garbled data
>   B. & # 9986 ; & # 10004 ; & # 10013 ;
>   C. A blank line due to charset mismatch

The expected answer is C, I expected it to be A - and when I ran that code, I got garbled data (Answer A)! So I wonder if PHPs behaviour had been changed recently or if this is an error in the test?

Comment: Where did you find that question and its incorrect answer?

Comment: That came from the dubious site http://testpassport.de (you can read an excerpt here: http://pdf.testpassport.de/200-530.pdf) - and that has been recommended by my trainer...

Comment: Yes, I see, they have "die autoritärsten Informationen" about  Zend-Technologies certification. I don't think it means what they think it means :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware that PHP behaviour has changed in that respect. However, the HTML standard has changed.

Prior to HTML 4, numeric character references such as `&#9986;` where interpreted with respect to the document character set (which is specified in the *Content Type* header field). It is reasonable that, as the code point 9986 does not exist in ISO 8859-1, nothing would be printed.

Since HTML 4, numeric character references are interpreted as Unicode code points. So `echo '&#9986;&#10004;&#10013;';` should print `✂✔✝` regardless of what the content type header field says about the character set. It is reasonable to call `✂✔✝` *Garbled data*, if one is not familiar with the Unicode Dingbats block.

Comment: Thanks for that. The test is supposed to cover PHP 5.3, so I guess we can safely assume HTML4-behaviour :-)